# What is the function of the "Vary: Accept" HTTP header?

Tags: http, caching, proxy

I use PHP to generate dynamic Web pages. As stated on the following tutorial (see link below), the MIME type of XHTML documents should be "application/xhtml+xml" when $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'] allows it. Since you can serve the same page with 2 different MIMEs ("application/xhtml+xml" and "text/html") you should set the "Vary" HTTP header to "Accept". This will help the cache on proxies.

Link:
http://keystonewebsites.com/articles/mime_type.php

Now I'm not sure of the implication of:
header('Vary: Accept');
I'm not really sure of what 'Vary: Accept' will precisely do...

The only explanation I found is:

> After the Content-Type header, a Vary
>   header is sent to (if I understand it
>   correctly) tell intermediate caches,
>   like proxy servers, that the content
>   type of the document varies depending
>   on the capabilities of the client
>   which requests the document.
>   http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200408/content_negotiation/

Anyone can give me a "real" explanation of this header (**with that value**). I think I understand things like:
Vary: Accept-Encoding
where the cache on proxies could be based on the encoding of the page served, but I don't understand:
Vary: Accept

Comment: Frankly - don't bother. Leaving aside the flaws in the implementation on that site, the only time you are going to get benefits from serving with an XML content-type is when you do things that can't be done in text/html - and if all you are doing is switching out the Doctype and xmlns, then you aren't going to be doing those things. Stick to text/html. For that matter, you might as well stick to HTML 4.01.

Comment: Yeah I understand this and I think "problems" like this one arise far too often in Web development. Thanks to "should" in specifications / RFCs!

Comment: You should probably read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/17/Vary-Header-Prevents-Caching-in-IE.aspx before you consider using VARY.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va6qtaiZRHg) have a good explanation about `Vary:` header.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

- The [`cache-control`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header is the primary mechanism for an HTTP server to tell a caching proxy the "freshness" of a response.  (i.e., how/if long to store the response in the cache)
- In some situations, `cache-control` directives are insufficient.  A discussion from the HTTP working group is archived [here,](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Issues/vary-header.html) describing a page that changes only with language.  This is *not* the correct use case for the vary header, but the context is valuable for our discussion.  (Although I believe the Vary header would solve the problem in that case, there is a Better Way.) From that page:

> *[`Vary`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44) is strictly for those cases where it's hopeless or excessively complicated for a proxy to replicate what the server would do.*

- [RFC2616 "Header-Field Definitions"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.44) describes the header usage from the server perspective, [RFC2616 "Caching Negotiated Responses"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.6) from a caching proxy perspective.  It's intended to specify a set of HTTP request headers that determine uniqueness of a request.

A contrived example:

Your HTTP server has a large landing page.  You have two slightly different pages with the same URL, depending if the user has been there before.  You distinguish between requests and a user's "visit count" based on Cookies.  But -- since your server's landing page is so large, you want intermediary proxies to cache the response if possible.

The URL, Last-Modified and Cache-Control headers are insufficient to give this insight to a caching proxy, but if you add `Vary: Cookie`, the cache engine will add the Cookie header to its caching decisions.

Finally, for small traffic, dynamic web sites -- I have always found the simple `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store` and `Pragma: no-cache` sufficient.

Edit -- to more precisely answer your question:  the HTTP request header 'Accept' defines the Content-Types a client can process.  If you have two copies of the same content at the same URL, differing only in Content-Type, then using `Vary: Accept` could be appropriate.

**Update 11 Sep 12:**

I'm including a couple links that have appeared in the comments since this comment was originally posted.  They're both excellent resources for real-world examples (and problems) with Vary: Accept; Iif you're reading this answer you need to read those links as well.

The first, from the outstanding EricLaw, on Internet Explorer's behavior with the Vary header and some of the challenges it presents to developers:  [Vary Header Prevents Caching in IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/17/Vary-Header-Prevents-Caching-in-IE.aspx).  In short, IE (pre IE9) does not cache any content that uses the Vary header because the request cache does not include HTTP Request headers.   EricLaw (Eric Lawrence in the real world) is a Program Manager on the IE team.

The second is from Eran Medan, and is an on-going discussion of Vary-related unexpected behavior in Chrome: [Backing doesn't handle Vary header correctly](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94369).  It's related to IE's behavior, except the Chrome devs took a different approach -- though it doesn't appear to have been a deliberate choice.

Comment: Beware of this in conjunction with back browser button in Chrome, there is sort of a flame war on this bug (which is now wontfix for some reason) http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=94369

Comment: @EranMedan The Chrome bug has since been fixed.

Answer (score 67):

`Vary: Accept` simply says that the response was generated based on the `Accept` header in the request. A request with a different `Accept` header might get a different response.

(You can see that the linked PHP code looks at `$HTTP_ACCEPT`. That's the value of the `Accept` request header.)

To HTTP caches, this means that the response must be cached with extra care. It is only going to be a valid match for later requests *with exactly the same `Accept` header*.

Now this only matters if the page is cacheable in the first place. By default, PHP pages aren't. A PHP page can mark the output as cacheable by sending certain headers (`Expires`, for example). But whether and how to do that is a different question.

Comment: is it "might get" or is it "should get" ?

Comment: @Pacerier "might get" is correct. `Vary: Accept` does not mean that every single possible distinct `Accept` header value produces a different and unique response. It only means that a different `Accept` header *might* produce a different response.

Answer (score 2):

This [google webmaster video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va6qtaiZRHg) has a very good explanation about HTTP `Vary` header.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually a significant number of new features coming soon (and already in Chrome) that make the `Vary` header extremely useful. For example, consider [Client Hinting](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/automating-resource-selection-with-client-hints). When used in connection with images, for example, client hinting allows a server to optimize resources such as images depending on:

- Image Width
- Viewport Width
- Type of encoding supported by browser (think WebP)
- Downlink (essentially network speed)

So a server which supports those features would set the `Vary` header to indicate that.

Chrome advertises WebP support by setting "image/webp" as part of the `Vary` header for each request. So a server might rewrite an image as WebP if the browser supports it, so the proxy would need to check the header so as to not cache a WebP image and then serve it to a browser that doesn't support WebP. Obviously, if your server doesn't do that, it wouldn't matter. So since the server's response varies on the `Accept` request header, the response must include that so as not to confuse proxies:

```
Vary: Accept
```

Another example might be image width. On a mobile browser the `Width` header might be quite small for a responsive image, in comparison with what it would be  if viewed from a desktop browser. So in that case `Width` would be added to the the `Vary` header is essential for proxy to not cache the small mobile version and serve it to desktop browsers, or vice versa. In that case, the header might include:

```
Vary: Accept, Width
```

Or in the case that a server supported all of the client hinting specs, the header would be something like:

```
Vary: Accept, DPR, Width, Save-Data, Downlink
```