# Vary Accept-Encoding header don't works

Tags: .htaccess, header, vary

I added next lines in .htaccess, which I found here [How to specify vary accept encoding header in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641197/how-to-specify-vary-accept-encoding-header-in-htaccess)

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
       <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
         Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
       </FilesMatch>
     </IfModule>
```

but it isn't works, also I checked phpinfo (Loaded Modules: mod_headers...).
I use Page Speed plugin and I can't see this header in my css file.
Why it isn't works?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want use this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
     Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
   </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

with semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Add this one in .htaccess file ,it will work

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other examples doesn't work, try this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Vary "Accept-Encoding"
</IfModule>
```