# Responding to google page speed suggestion regarding compression

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

Google page speed tool tells me this:  *"Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network"*

and of course lists all my .js and .css files.

Researching here eventually led me to this question:

[How to Specify "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641197/how-to-specify-vary-accept-encoding-header-in-htaccess)

Which seems to say that for just .js and .css files all I would need to do is this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
        Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Can someone confirm that this is the current "best practice" for this objective and that it is failsafe, assuming the user is on a modern browser (e.g. not < IE7 for example)

Thanks!