# Gzip compression (mod_deflate) not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, compression, gzip

I have just added, or tried to add, gzip compression to my website in order to make it faster. This is the code I have put into `.htaccess` I got from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641197/how-to-specify-vary-accept-encoding-header-in-htaccess).

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    #The following line is enough for .js and .css
    AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css
    #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type:s
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml
    #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html 
</IfModule>
```

So now I'm using a firebug extension called PageSpeed to monitor gzip compression and it is not working. I also use http://gtmetrix.com/ and the results are the same. Can anyone explain to me what more I have to do to enable gzip compression? Big thanks!