# Adding compression to fonts

Tags: fonts, compression, webfonts, http-accept-header

I get this warning in a speed test from tools.pingdom.com: compressible resources should have a "Vary: Accept-Encoding" header

How can I compress this resource on my site: http://www.abrakadabra.fi/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
I serve these fonts locally from my server.

Comment: But the error is that your woff2 font, which is a compressed resource, is not being served by your server without a header that lets browsers do more intelligent things with it. You don't want to ask about how to turn on compression (your .woff2 is already compressed), you want to ask about "how do I add that header". To which the answer is: no idea, we need more details. Which server system are you using?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue Mike.

I'm using an Apache server with Gzip and Keep Alive enabled. 
I have no idea how to "add that header" and where I should add it. 

I would be happy to learn more about this issue, because it was very hard to find anything when searching the internet. 

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: remember to work that comment into your post: other people should be able to now find that information without needing to read the comments, and to then search SO again for this new information. For instance, if you search for how to  add that header to Apache, you'll find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641197/how-to-specify-vary-accept-encoding-header-in-htaccess