# Should I include media type in my ETag?

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, http-caching

When adding an ETag to an HTTP response, should I include the media type? Of course, I understand that the ETag is opaque, but here is an example:

- Say I have a client that requests a Person in application/json.  I look it up and create my ETag and send back the JSON representation of the person
- Now the same client makes another request for the same person (which has not been modified) at the same URI but wants it in application/xml.

Clearly it is incorrect to simply return a 304, but my question is, in the second request, would I expect the ETags to match but no cache based on the Accept header (or the content header).  Also, is it even possible that the cache will have two representations from the same URI, or would you always  have an invalid cache every time your Content-Type switched?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different representations need different entity tags.

See http://trac.tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/trac/ticket/39.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I must say I am surprised.  I guess that's why it is called an "Entity" Tag and not a Resource Tag.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you can send the same Etag for different representations. As long as you specify, that they should be cached as two different entities, in your response.
This can be done using the Vary field, as described in RFC 2616

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

> 14.44 Vary
>
> The Vary field value indicates the set of request-header fields that
>      fully determines, while the response is fresh, whether a cache is
>      permitted to use the response to reply to a subsequent request
>      without revalidation. For uncacheable or stale responses, the Vary
>      field value advises the user agent about the criteria that were used
>      to select the representation.

Using a `Vary: Accept` should be appropriate.

Comment: Please don't cite RFC 2616, when the respective working group has acknowledged that it's not clear enough, *and* a pointer to the clarification has already been posted in a reply.

Comment: I feel that this is somewhat unfair. As I came to understand the reply to the question, described how bad server implementations creates cache issues, and not a flaw in the specification itself. I think your judgment goes agains what others agree is a appropriate use of the header Vary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975416/trying-to-understand-the-vary-http-header. The top answer gives the same reply as me and is highly praised.

Comment: Cleric: if you believe the new HTTP spec is wrong then I encourage you to come over to the HTTPbis WG mailing list and argue the case. The documents are close to Last Call, so this is the time. BTW: I agree that you need to use Vary; what I disagree with is that this is sufficient; thus the other answer you linked to is irrelevant (because etags aren't even mentioned over there)

Comment: Im pretty sure I did not argue that the new HTTP spec is wrong, but I would love to have some input on the subject. Which I sadly do not have. But I stand corrected, the link I put forth does not talk about Etags at all. I will have to do some further research into how Etags are interpreted and why Vary does not suffice. If you have some links on the subject I would be thankful.

Comment: That is not correct as per https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-2.1. What you described is a "weak validator": "Likewise, a validator is weak if it is shared by two or more representations of a given resource at the same time, unless those representations have identical representation data."