# Chrome displays ajax response when pressing back button

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, back-button

I've come across a problem that if I use jQuery's Get method to get some content, if I click back, instead of it actually going back one page in the history, it instead shows the content returned by the Ajax query.

Any idea's?

http://www.dameallans.co.uk/preview/allanian-society/news/56/Allanian-test

On the above page, if you use the pagination below the list of comments you will notice when clicking back after changing a page, that it shows the HTML content used to generate the list of comments.

I've noticed it doesn't always do it, but if you click on a different page a few times and click the back button, it simply displays json text within the window instead of the website.

For some reason, this is only affecting Chrome as IE and Firefox work ok.

Comment: did you figure out a way to resolve this? I'm having the same problem as well.

Answer (score 47):

Make sure your AJAX requests use a different URL from the full HTML documents. Chrome caches the most recent request even if it is just a partial.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108425

Comment: I have been pulling my hair out with this bug for a number of weeks. Thank you!

Comment: Quick solution:  Append "?ajax=true" to your url in the ajax request.

Comment: The answer should actually be "make sure the URL is not cached" for which just one solution might be using different URLs...

Comment: I don't quite understand this issue. On one hand it's because of cache, and on the other hand it doesn't use the cache. If it did, it wouldn't generate new response. My app displays different response for Ajax and different for non-ajax and on back, Chrome displays this Ajax one. Which means it doesn't use cache. It's ridiculous, how it even cache related to Ajax?

Answer (score 21):

Just in case you are using jQuery with History API (or some library like history.js), you should change $.getJSON to $.ajax with cache set to false:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function (json) {...}
});
```

Comment: The `cache: false` option works by appending a timestamp to the URL, so if you're using jQuery it's the best solution. It only applies to HEAD and GET requests, and is set automatically when `dataType` is `script` or `jsonp`

Answer (score 21):

Actually this is the expected behavior of caching system according to specs and not a chrome issue. The cache only differentiate requests base on URL and request method (get, post, ...), not any of the request headers.

But there is a **Vary** header to tell browser to consider some headers when checking the cache. For example by adding **Vary:X-Requested-With** to the server response the browser knows that this response vary if request **X-Requested-With** header is changed. Or by adding **Vary:Content-Type** to the server response the browser knows that this response vary if request **Content-Type** header is changed.

You can add this line to your router for PHP:

```
header('Vary:X-Requested-With');
```

And use a middleware in node.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.header('Vary', 'X-Requested-With');
});
```

Comment: Works for me. I have to have same url for ajax and for classic income from url bar. Ajax library what I use does not have cache=false....

Comment: This is actually the most elegant answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can also add a random value to the end of the ajax url. This will ignore the previous chrome cache and will request a new version

```
url = '/?'+Math.random()
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add the following header to the **Response** headers :

```
Vary: Accept
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't give different urls for each ajax request as it was an ajax pagination, declaring no cache on headers did nothing, so i included a little javascript in the view only when headers were for the ajax request:

```
<script>
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    window.location = "<?php echo $this->here; ?>";
}
</script>
```

It is a dirty trick, but it works, if the ajax content is normally loaded, the container has Jquery loaded so it does nothing. But if you load the ajax supposed content without the surrounding content, Jquery is missing (at least in my case), so i redirect to the current page requesting a normal GET page with all the headers and scripts.

If you put it in the top of the page, the user won't notice because it won't wait till the page loads, it will redirect as soon as the browser gets this 4 lines...

Replace here; ?> by the current url in your APP, this was a CakePhp 2.X

Answer (score 1):

Still had this problem in 2021 in Chrome.

Problem is doing underlying ajax request to the same url as the one the user is currently on.
I was working in **Symfony** and the complete fix that did the work for me was

```
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('s-maxage', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);

/**
 * from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975677/5418514
 *
 * The HTTP request header 'Accept' defines the Content-Types a client can process.
 * If you have two copies of the same content at the same URL, differing only in Content-Type,
 * then using Vary: Accept could be appropriate.
 */
$response->headers->set('Vary', 'Accept');
```

Answer (score 0):

The @abraham's answer is right.
I just wanted to post a solution for Rails: all you need is just add different path to `routes.rb`.

In example, I have `resource :people` and I want to compose index page from ajax parts one of those is list of people. The straightforward way is to create `index.js.erb` and to load partial via ajax using `url: people_path`. But here occurs the issue.

So, for Rails, it needs just add a different route, like

`get 'people_list', to: 'people#index', as: :people_list, format: :js`

Answer (score 0):

If I want to use index method of a laravel controller returns both html and json response, I add a get parameter at the end of the endpoint to pass browser caching:

```
axios.get(url, {params: {ajax: 1}})
```