# Ajax response in browser history

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on `localhost/mysite/users`. On this page there is user listing and the records are coming from ajax request.

I am facing a strange issue, whenever I press back button and then forward button; on page `localhost/mysite/users` only the ajax listing is shown, all the page design and other elements are deleted.

Can you please let me know the reason and suggest some solution?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // on page load get listing from this page
        sendReq('localhost/mysite/users');

});
```

On users page:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    // get users
} else {
    // page rendered
}
```

Comment: No, not without some sort of code that shows what's actually going on.

Comment: @spender Code has been updated! On page load, I send ajax request to get user list from DB other page elements are rendered normally.

Comment: @spender Now when I hit Back - Forward button, I am only left with ajax list.

Comment: I don't know what `sendReq` is.

Comment: @spender Its just a function to send $.ajax request.

Comment: and in its parameter is the `url path`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're setting headers properly.

```
Header('Content-Type: application/json');
Header("Cache-Control: no-store");
```

Comment: I found that FF 44 handles the back button without getting tripped up by the AJAX response, but Chrome 51 doesn't. It might be a Chrome specific problem? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956255/chrome-displays-ajax-response-when-pressing-back-button