# How do I make Symfony ignore the cache when user calls a page after logging in?

Tags: php, caching, symfony

Im Using Symfony 2.3, and I have enabled the Symfony Reverse Proxy cache. It works, but not as I want it and not sure what to do.

So, User comes to site, visits a page. Logs in, navigates back to page viewed before login but is served the page he was shown before logging in, without any of the login changes. When logged in, I force pages not to cache, but its too late it seems when a page has already been cached by the reverse proxy, that cached page is server regardless.

Is there some way before a page is served via a cache I can determine that the request is coming from someone logged in so cache must be ignored?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732454/no-cache-header-with-annotation) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) and make sure you tell the reverse proxy not to cache those routes by adding the right headers to your response for your reverse proxy and the user's cache.

```
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
$response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);
```

Comment: I don't want to prevent the caching of pages, basically, when a logged in user requests a page I want to bypass the cache, in app.PHP the regular kernel gets converted to a cache kernel, I need somehow to check the regular kernel to see if the request is from an authenticated user, if so don't create the cache kernel.