# Symfony 2.6 logout back button (CakePHP)

Tags: php, symfony, cakephp, model-view-controller, browser-cache

After trying a lot of different ways (success handler, cache directives, changing routes, overriding methods, etc.) I haven't been able to logout a user (using the FOSUserBundle) disabling her to see previous pages when pressing the back-button of the browser.

Is there a way to do it in Symfony 2.6?

In CakePHP this works perfectly in a Controller

```
public function logout() {

    session_destroy();
    $this->Auth->deny('*');
    $this->Auth->shutdown('*');
    $this->Session->setFlash('Logout succesful - no back button issue.');
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following headers to the top of the page in your application:

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); 
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 header("Expires: 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to logout page:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('fos_user_security_logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send no-cache directive to the browser
Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41566590/1154919