# IE 9+ ignores ETag value change and returns cached response

Tags: internet-explorer, caching, etag

The Etag provided cache validation that works well with FF & chrome, but IE seems to ignore the Etag value and always returns the cached response.

The server response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Jul 2014 06:01:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
ETag: a7628382056ddd13b7e06991571fd3ad
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 4360
```

when client sends a conditional get request

```
If-None-Match: 71fb49ecd6f85545693dec0e78ae2131
```

The request is not sent at all and IE returns the cached response. It transparent when ETag value is the same but a problem when ETag is different.

The only solution that worked for me was adding header

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I monitored the network and it forces IE to validate the ETag value.
 
problem is solved!
However I didn't find any official solution for this problem. I used the post [Make IE to cache resources but always revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017454/make-ie-to-cache-resources-but-always-revalidate/24604129#24604129) as a reference but most of the information was irrelevant to my problem.

if you have another idea or advise please share

Comment: Your server is probably returning a very recent `Last-Modified` header value, so IE trusts it won't change in the near future.  The `no-cache` technique is valid, the only official documentation you need is [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) (or a [superceding one](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234)).  Another much less reliable technique is to include a query string in the URL that has never been used by the same client, which, as a bad side-effect, also fills the cache with things that won't be reused.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer uses some heuristics for caching responses. You can read more at [Caching Improvements in Internet Explorer 9](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9/) in the *Heuristic Cache Improvements* section:

> If a Last-Modified header wasn’t present in the server’s response,
>   then Internet Explorer will fall back to the “Once per browser
>   session” revalidation behavior.

and:

> if the response does have a Last-Modified time, the heuristic
>   expiration value SHOULD be no more than some fraction of the interval
>   since that time. A typical setting of this fraction might be 10%.

What you want is to bypass these heuristics and force IE to revalidate the content with the server. To do so, please check [Make IE to cache resources but always revalidate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5017454/1010492) and its answer. The key headers seem to be:

```
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Feb 2011 13:52:26 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, private
```

Bonus: please also see the section about the *Vary Improvements* in the earlier link:

> If a response contains a Vary directive that specifies a header other
>   than Accept-Encoding, Host, or User-Agent (or any combination of
>   these) then Internet Explorer will still cache the response if the
>   response contains an ETAG header. However, that response will be
>   treated as stale and a conditional HTTP request will be made before
>   reuse to determine if the cached copy is valid.

While it does not say what happens when no `Vary` header specified, it might be worth playing with this value (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1975677/1010492))