# Varnish handling different from different methods of request

Tags: node.js, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

(Varnish 2.1.5)

I've got some strange situation in my Varnish. I'm trying to invalidate cache objects through PURGE requests initiated from NodeJS.

My testing consists of requesting the object, letting it cache, then do a purge request, then request it again (resulting in a fetch), and then request it again resulting in a hit of the refreshed cache object.

When I test this through the Firefox debug console, it works fine. All steps seem to work as expected. When I test the entire process in NodeJS, it works as expected, just fine. However, when I let the object cache through Firefox, and then try to invalidate it through NodeJS, it reports a 404 Not in cache.

I'm a 100% sure I'm using the same URI, and I have no idea why it acts this way. Has anyone else experienced this problem? And if yes, what is the solution to this problem?

This is my VCL:

```
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "80";
}

acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "*loadbalancer-ip*";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            if(!client.ip ~ purge) {
                    error 405 "Not allowed.";
            }
            return (lookup);
    } else if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|xml)$") {
            unset req.http.Cookie;
            return (lookup);
    } else {
            return (pass);
    }
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            set obj.ttl = 0s;
            error 200 "Purged";
    }
}

sub vcl_miss {
    if (req.request == "PURGE") {
            error 404 "Not in cache.";
    }
}


sub vcl_fetch {
    if (req.url ~ "(?i)\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|xml)$") {
            unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
            return (deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "HIT";
    } else {
            set resp.http.X-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

As you can see, my configuration is pretty straight forward. This configuration is for testing purposes, I know using the loadbalancer IP is not safe and I will change it to use the Forwarded-For IP once everything works.

Answer (score 0):

With a little help of this thread:
[What is the function of the "Vary: Accept" HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975416/what-is-the-function-of-the-vary-accept-http-header)

I came to know that it considers the Vary header when determining whether to cache or not, and which version to get from cache.

In my case, the Vary header contained the User-Agent, which is why I was getting different results from different methods.